# Unable to launch war in vsCode

Tags: java, tomcat, visual-studio-code, war

I have a problem i'm triing to launch a war with the tomcat server.

In fact, when i click to launch the war (run on tomcat server) and i go to a localhost:8080, the page of the server says that no wars are on server.

I have try to put the war directly in the application folder of the server, but it's the same thing.

Can someone help me ?

Is it a problem with the war ? i have try with an other war, it's the same thing ?

I'm using a window 10.

Thanks you

Comment: try adding it using the tomcat manager page?

Answer (score 0):

.war is a archive file.
You Must Open the file. You can rename the file to .tar and use any Tar Tape-archiver implementation.
Or you can use 7zip to Open the file.

Comment: Can you explain how the launch the file after unzip on the tomcat server ? I'm using VsCode

Comment: copy all files form the .war file to the WebApp folder

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the Extension **Tomcat for Java**
2. Turn to **Tomcat Servers** in left side, and add tomcat
3. Right click the tomcat and choose **start**, after it's started successfully, right click and choose `Debug War Package`, this will debug the war, if you don't want it, just stop the debugging
4. Rigth click the war then choose **Open in Browser**:
   [image]

Comment: Thank you i'have tried this but i have the same problem, tomcat have a problem to launch the war, is it a problem with the war ? it's strange because i have tried with an other war and it's the same.

Comment: @SofianeSidiLarbi. Can you share your war for me to test? If it encounters the same error in my tomcat, maybe something wrong with the war package.